# Getting the last X posts, but in ascending order of time

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

I have some 'Events' custom post types. On the home page of my site, I'd like to show the last X events, but in ascending order of time (earliest first). Where I am stuck is that to get the "last X" entries, I need to put the event date field in DESC order in the SQL, but after those posts are retrieved, I need to order them in ascending order.

```
// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'posts_per_page'    => 2,
    'meta_key'          => 'from_datetime',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));
```

Here `from_datetime` is my custom field using ACF. This works. It gets me the last two events. But they're in descending order of time, which means the further event is first.

Is there a way to get the last 2 events, but in ascending order of time from get_posts itself, without resorting to some array or something from the results?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the last parameter with `ASC` like `'order => 'ASC'` ? I think it will solve your problem. So your full code will be like-

```
// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'posts_per_page'    => 2,
    'meta_key'          => 'from_datetime',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    // Here is the main trick happening.
    'order'             => 'ASC'
));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, this is how I had it before. But because of ASC, this gives me events that have already passed. So if I could somehow bar those entries from the above query. I found something online using WP_Query which had some variation called "after" a certain date. Is there any way to limit the `get_posts` to only posts after `now`?